# iterator with custom object pointer list

Tags: c++

I made a list of custom objects here is part of my code :

```
list<Carre*> mechants;
mechants.push_front(new Carre(joueur.getX()-1500,joueur.getY()+100));left = false;
for(list<Carre*>::iterator i=mechants.begin(); i != mechants.end(); ++i)
{
    *i->IA(joueur);
}
```

error: request for member 'IA' in '* i.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator->()', which is of pointer type 'Carre*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

Mayby the problem is i make a list of Carre* and i should try to do a list of Carre instead but i don't know how to add them in that case.
I already tried to do **i->IA(joueur) without succes;
I never used a list of custom object before so i don't know what to do.

edit : IA(Joueur) is a function of class Carre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*i->IA(joueur);` is trying to do `*(i->IA(joueur));`

What you want is parentheses around `i`:

`(*i)->IA(joueur);`

Comment: Well thanks, i suppose since it's a pointer of pointer, you the arrow isn't enough to "protect it" from miss understanding from compiler.

Comment: @user3162867: The problem is that the dereference from `*` is getting applied to the return value of `IA`, not to `i`, which is why parentheses are needed. As you originally wrote it, it's the same as doing `*((*i).IA(joueur));` but what you really want is `(*(*i)).IA(joueur);` (or equivalently, `(*i)->IA(joueur);`). Originally, `*` and `->` were dereferencing two different things (`IA`'s return value and `i`, respectively), due to operator precedence and associativity. Adding the parentheses makes sure `i` is dereferenced twice, and `IA`'s return value is not dereferenced.

Comment: Ok i get it, the kind of stuff i should not forget, thanks for your help, may I ask how to make my problem "solved"?

Comment: On the left side of my answer, there should be a check mark. If you click it, it will accept this answer as the answer to your question and mark it solved. :)